# API call every 40 sec in SwiftUI

Tags: swift

I have to call the API every 40 seconds, I wrote the code, and the time comes randomly. This is weird behavior.

```
 func startTimer() {
    
    timer = Timer.publish(every: 40.0, on: .main, in: .common)

    .autoconnect()
    .sink { _ in
    // API call
    }
}
```

Comment: Timer isn’t guaranteed to be exact but SwiftUI shouldn’t be included in this at all. SwiftUI is for UI.

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for the quick response.


func startTimer() {
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 40, repeats: true){ timer in
            // API call
            
        }
    }. 

This function is inside the ObservableObject. this is also not working properly

Comment: `Timer` is not particularly accurate. It tends to suffer from significant jitter too. A `Timer` will not fire until at least the requested period has passed but not necessarily precisely when then the period occurs. The best strategy is to run the timer faster (say every second) and compare the elapsed time since you last took an action (using a saved `Date`) to determine if you should take the action again.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks,  I want to call API every 40 sec. API fetches user coordinates (long and lat).  Can you please help?